# Refresh page after ajax form submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Hello i need to know how to refresh the page after i submit an ajax form.
Atm i'm using an onClick function it seems it refreshes the page but i still need to press f5 to see the changed i made.

js:

```
 <script>
    function reloadPage()
      {
      location.reload()
      }
    </script>
```

form:

```
echo'<form class="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=\'clase/app/admin_activare_oferta.php\'>';
echo'<input  type="hidden" name="id_oferta"  value="'.$oferta.'">';
echo'<input type="submit" id="activ" value="" onclick="reloadPage()"></form>';
```

I know why i need to press on the button twice to see the change, because i need to run that refresh after ajax submits.

Comment: It doesn't seem like an AJAX form to me

Comment: Just use `document.location.reload(true)`

Comment: i didnt post the script for it, it is an ajax form

Comment: not working DaHaKa i need to press the subbmit button twice to see the change

Comment: Why would you want to reload the page? The whole idea of AJAX is that you don't have to reload the page anymore.

Answer (score 0):

location.href or location.replace should do the trick:

read this:

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Location-href-vs-Location-replace-The-Difference-Between-JavaScript-Redirect-Methods.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In IE you should use window.parent.location.href